# Maven Tomcat Integration for Project with Multiple Independent Services

Tags: tomcat, maven, jetty, maven-plugin, maven-jetty-plugin

We have the following project setup:

```
Root (pom)
 |
 +-- s1: Service 1 (war)
 +-- s2: Service 2 (war)
 +-- lib: Shared Library for Service 1 + 2 (jar)
 +-- intf: Service 1 Interface POJOs
```

Each is a maven project with its own pom:

```
Root.pom:
...
<modules>
  <module>s1</module>
  ...
</modules>
```

And each subproject references it's parent project:

```
<parent>
   ....
</parent>
```

Maven compile/test targets work fine. But I'm messing up with the tomcat plugin, whenever I try to instantiate a locatl tomcat testing environment with:

```
mvn tomcat:run
```

It will only start **one of the services** (actually always the the first service in the `<modules>` section.

I would like to start both services, do you have similar experiences in your projects or any idea of how to make this in a nice way?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Where have you configured the tomcat plugin? in the root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recomment to make a separate maven module which contains the definition for the tomcat plugin and use the two services as dependencies...or you can use the cargo-maven-plugin to define a configuration where you can start two services within a single tomcat instance...like in this example: https://github.com/khmarbaise/scms/blob/master/scms-it/pom.xml

Comment: I actually used the first recommendation from you: one maven plugin to rule them all (as a webservice) and it works like a charm. thanks!